# wkhtmltopdf scrollbars showing on pdf

Tags: amazon-ec2, wkhtmltopdf

On test machine I produce a PDF using wkhtmltopdf and no horizontal scrollbars show in the outputted PDF.
When I try from my amazon EC2 instance, the font looks bigger and scrollbars appear on a table.

Test machine output - using wk 0.12.1
[image: test machine pdf]

EC2 output - amazon EC2/using wk 0.11.0
[image: EC2 output]

FIXED - updated EC2 to 0.12.1 and issue was resolved.

The html is identical, has anyone else experienced this?- any advice welcome TQ

Comment: good idea - this fixed issue  TQ

Comment: Cool mind if I add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one thing you could do is either ensure you are using the same version on locally and in production, or use --zoom on the EC2 version so you can zoom out slightly as it looks to be an issue fitting the content onto the screen